# Getting an Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.com/ when trying to change the href

Tags: jquery, href, attr

I am trying to use jquery to change the href.  For some reason I keep getting the error

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.com/

Here is my code

```
$('.testing-test-test-two').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Here is my html

```
<li role="presentation" class="active dual-tab-toggle plans-tabs">
        <a href="#one-tab" class="testing-test-test-two" aria-controls="tab-one" role="tab" data-link="seeker-header" data-toggle="tab">
          Job seekers
        </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: What kind of element are you modifying?

Comment: Maybe you need add your `html` too

Comment: `data-toggle="tab""` extra quote.

Comment: The error is generated elsewhere, not this line. Click the filename/line number at the right side of console and post the correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have and extra " after the `data-toogle="tab"`, it should work correctly this way:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active dual-tab-toggle plans-tabs">
  <a href="#one-tab" class="testing-test-test-two" aria-controls="tab-one" role="tab" data-link="seeker-header" data-toggle="tab">
          Job seekers
        </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: He's edited that typo out of the question. And it wouldn't cause this error anyway.